# How to send contact form detail including userEmail on form through codeigniter on web-server not through local-host

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

There is lots of answer about send mail though local-host with contact form data and I am successfully do this. But when I am up my website on server (hostinger) then I am going stuck with problem.

I want to send all data of contact form on my email and I am get contact form data on email but user-email field data not comes in email and if I'm pass email field data on form, it's send email successfully but mail not comes in mail account and not show any error, and also on console show request post successfully.

If I'm comment user-email field data then every thing going good but with user-email, I got nothing on email box.
If any one have idea how to pass email value, then pleas shear your knowledge. I am very much tired with this problem and I am put 2 days on this problem and still have no clue.

My code is - 
application/view/email_temp.php -

```
<html style="background:#5D849E;background-size:cover;height:100%;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);padding-left:35px;padding-right:35px;padding-top:35px;padding-bottom:50px;width:650px;float:left;left:50%;position:absolute;margin-top:30px;margin-left:-300px;-moz-border-radius:7px;-webkit-border-radius:7px;">
                  <form>
                    <h1 align="center" style="color:#3c3c3c;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:500;font-size:28px;border-radius:0;line-height:22px;background-color:#fbfbfb;padding:13px 13px 13px 54px;margin-bottom: 10px;width:100%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);"><b>New one Contact You!</b>
                    </h1><br>
                        <table align="left" style="color:#3c3c3c;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:500;font-size:22px;border-radius:0;line-height:22px;background-color:#fbfbfb;padding:13px 13px 13px 54px;margin-bottom: 10px;width:100%;    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr height="50px;"><th align="left">Company Name : </th><td><?php echo $cname;?></td></tr>
                            <tr height="50px;"><th align="left">Name : </th><td><?php echo $name;?></td></tr>

                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Phone : </th><td><?php echo $phone;?></td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Address : </th><td><?php echo $address;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">State : </th><td><?php echo $state;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Contry : </th><td><?php echo $country;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Accreditation For which Standard : </th><td><?php echo $accre;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Describe Your requirements : </th><td><?php echo $requir;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="50px;">
                              <th align="left">Email : </th><td><?php echo $name;?></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

application/controller/ContactUs.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class ContactUs extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() { parent::__construct(); $this->load->helper('url'); $this->load->library('email'); }
public function contactMailSend()
    {          
            $data = array(
        'cname' => $this->input->post('contact_cname'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('contact_name'),
        'userEmail' => $this->input->post('cemail'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('contact_phone'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('contact_address'),
        'state' => $this->input->post('contact_state'),
        'country' => $this->input->post('contact_country'),
        'accre' => $this->input->post('contact_accre'),
        'requir' => $this->input->post('contact_requir')
        );
       $subject="Urgent || New Persone || Contact You";
       $this->load->library('email');
       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
       $this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
       $this->email->to('abc@gmail.com');
       $this->email->subject($subject);
       $body=$this->load->view('email_temp', $data, true);
       $this->email->message($body);       
       if($this->email->send())
       {
           echo "Mail send successfully";
       }
       else
       {
           echo "Not send mail";
        }
}
?>
```

application/view/contact.php

```
<!-- Link for toaster -->
<!-- <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- End -->

<!-- Css for toaster -->
<style type="text/css">

#toast-container > .toast {
    background-image: none !important;
}

#toast-container > .toast:before {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 18px;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: auto 0.5em auto -1.5em;
}        
#toast-container > .toast-warning:before {
    content: "\f003";
}
#toast-container > .toast-error:before {
    content: "\f001";
}
#toast-container > .toast-info:before {
    content: "\f005";
}
#toast-container > .toast-success:before {
    content: "\f003";
}

</style>
<!-- End -->    

<section id="inner-headline">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
                    <li>Contact Us<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="col-md-8">

                    <h1>Contact Us </a></h1>
                    <hr>    

<form id="contact-form" onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" action="<?php base_url(); ?>ContactUs/contactMailSend" role="form">

    <div class="messages"></div>

    <div class="controls">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_cname">Companyname *</label>
                    <input id="contact_cname" type="text" name="contact_cname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Company Name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_name">Name *</label>
                    <input id="contact_name" type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Name *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <input type="email" name="cemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_phone">Phone</label>
                    <input id="contact_phone" type="tel" name="contact_phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_address">Address *</label>
                    <input id="contact_address" type="text" name="contact_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Address *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_state">State *</label>
                    <input id="contact_state" type="text" name="contact_state" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter State *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_country">Country *</label>
                    <input id="contact_country" type="text" name="contact_country" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter Country *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_accre">Accreditation For which Standard *</label>
                    <input id="contact_accre" type="text" name="contact_accre" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter enquiry standard *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_requir">Describe Your requirements *</label>
                    <textarea id="contact_requir" name="contact_requir" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe Your requirements *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a describtion of requirements."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
<br><br><br>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h3>Mail Us -</h3>
        <a href="mailto:iafuk.org@gmail.com"><strong>iafuk.org@gmail.com</strong></a>
        <br><br>
        <h3>Address -</h3>
        <address>
            <strong>IAF-UK Akkreditering Forum Limited</strong><br>
             Suite 20, 196 Rose Street<br>
             Edinbugh, Eh2 4AT, UK 
        </address>      
        <strong>Phone - (123) 364-7562 / (123) 526-6892</strong>    
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

assets/js/validation.js - use for toaster at button click

```
function validate() {

$cname = document.getElementById('contact_cname');
$name = document.getElementById('contact_name');

$phone = document.getElementById('contact_phone');
$address = document.getElementById('contact_address');
$state = document.getElementById('contact_state');
$country = document.getElementById('contact_country');
$accre = document.getElementById('contact_accre');
$requir = document.getElementById('contact_requir');
if($cname.value == '' || $cname.value == null || $name.value == '' || $name.value == null || $phone.value == '' || $phone.value == null) {
    return false;
}
else {
    showToast();
return true;

}
}
```

Comment: show me the view file from where you posted data

Comment: I am include contact form and also one .js file which I am use for toaster at button click

Comment: first put your email libraray ehthir at the top or in __construct()

Comment: email library already included in __construct() and also loaded in contactMailSend()

Comment: I don't understand if I'm include <?php echo $userEmail?> in email_temp.php any where in table but if I am send any other vallue like name, address on the place of $userEmail; then email comes in my gmail box successfully. Mean every thing going great but only $userEmail; value not goes.

Comment: Pls print the $data array()  just before the $subject variable to which field is rendered and which are not

Comment: I just want to say if u have included in __construc() then why u r including in the method contactMailSend() again

Comment: I am remove form function and then check, not any success

Comment: when I am print $data array like - print_r($data);exit(); every thing I got on page including email value, but it's not pass on gmail

Comment: I got this on $data - Array ( [cname] => Dev Company [name] => ABC [userEmail] => abc@gmail.com [phone] => 98987344 [address] => Mayurvihar Phase 1 [state] => Delhi [country] => India [accre] => ISO 9001 [requir] => I want information about iso9001 )

Comment: U see every field is redered properly means if there is error then it is in the  email portion: we have to diagnose them

Comment: what is this  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); I didn't find this method in email library So remove it;

Comment: Is view_temp file is containing html?

Comment: view_temp is html file for designed email send and ok I will remove set_newline("\r\n"); May be it's for content-type="text" for giving new line and new row.

Comment: is there any protocol or any other library file which I want to include for $userEmail. I am also change the $userEmail with $email, but still not get success, I really don't understand why only $userEmail not go with form, if problem with variable then not pass any variable value.

Comment: u can use helper email to validate the email

Comment: add this line in your  contactMailSend() function  $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

Comment: I am used this code which is I am save mail.php in application/config/mail.php folder where is all protocols and config data